# Package - Facade not found

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I'm setting up a new package in the workbench but I keep getting the error:

```
Class 'company\package\MyPackageFacade' not found
```

My classes are name spaced correctly.

I have performed this, both in the package and root:

```
composer dump-autoload
```

I have also tried:

```
php artisan dump-autoload
```

I've also checked the spelling of everything.

Where else am I going wrong?

Package.php

```
class Package {

  public static function test(){
    return "it works";
  }

}
```

PackageFacade.php

```
<?php namespace Company\Package;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade;

class Package extends Facade {


protected static function getFacadeAccessor() { return 'package'; }

}
```

PackageServiceProvider.php

```
<?php namespace Company\Package;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class MyPackageServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {

    protected $defer = false;

    public function boot()
    {
        $this->package('company\package');
    }

    public function register()
    {
        $this->app['privilege'] = $this->app->share(function($app)
        {
            return new Package;
        });
    }

    public function provides()
    {
        return array('package');
    }
```

}

In my apps config providers:

```
'Company\Package\PackageServiceProvider',
```

And aliases:

```
'Package'         => 'Company\Package\PackageFacade',
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your facade name should be

```
'Package'         => 'Company\Package\Package',
```

If you want PackageFacade, you have to change it to:

```
class PackageFacade extends Facade { ... }
```